# How to this link to create multinomial clustered standard error in R

Tags: multinomial

Does anyone knows how to use this paper (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/suppl/10.1177/0003122410395370/suppl_file/Davenport_online_supplement.pdf) to create a clustered standard error for multinomial in R?

I have multinom() model and want to cluster it by states but unable to figure out the code.

Thanks!

tried to use the sandwich clustered standard errors (CSE) with the Multinom() command, but it did not work. I also tried to run the mlogit() command, but my data set is too large (+1.4M) to use it.